# How do I create an Action to open another PDF at page with a zoom of Fit Page in iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

How do I make a `PdfAction` that will open another PDF at a specific page with the zoom level `Fit Page`? One of the constructors for `PdfAction` takes a PDF path and target page number, but it defaults the zoom to `Fit Width`. I don't see any methods/constructors that include a 'desired zoom' parameter. Am I not seeing it, or is there a way to change the zoom level once the `PdfAction` has been made?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var pdfAnnotation = PdfAnnotation.CreateLink(
    pdfStamper.Writer,
    linkOutline,
    PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_NONE,
    new PdfAction(pdfPath, targetPageNumber));

pdfAnnotation.BorderStyle = new PdfBorderDictionary(0.0F, 0);

pdfStamper.AddAnnotation(pdfAnnotation, sourcePageNumber);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the idiomatic solution to my problem, but I was able to update the zoom level after the `PdfAction` was created by replacing one of the hash table values:

```
var action = new PdfAction(pdfPath, targetPageNumber);

action.Remove(PdfName.D);
action.Put(PdfName.D, new PdfLiteral($@"[{targetPageNumber - 1} /Fit]"));


var pdfAnnotation = PdfAnnotation.CreateLink(
    pdfStamper.Writer,
    linkOutline,
    PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_NONE,
    action);

pdfAnnotation.BorderStyle = new PdfBorderDictionary(0.0F, 0);


pdfStamper.AddAnnotation(pdfAnnotation, sourcePageNumber);
```